# Determine close all tabs v/s close current tab

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, internet-explorer-11

How can I detect whether `onunload` event is triggered by `browser` close or `tab` close?

I have `onunload` event captured in the application and that works fine - to warn the user before leaving page. However, in case there are multiple tabs of the application open and if user selects to close the browser, user gets a prompt if he wants to **close all tabs**. Now, after hitting close all tabs, I do not want user to individually attend prompt(raised by `onunload` event) on all the tabs. If close all tabs is clicked `onunload` should be disabled.

So, can I capture that whether **close all tabs** is clicked in `onunload` event?

Comment: @mplungjan - the link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing] that you have marked duplicate does not answer my question. I want to determine the click of Close All Tabs button instead of browser or tab close. Edited question title.

Comment: The answer is still “not possible “